# No se puede depurar PHP en Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, linux, vscode, xdebug

Desde Ubuntu 18, con el servidor Apache, estoy intentando depurar mi proyecto realizado en PHP 7.2 desde Visual Studio Code con **Xdebug** pero me da el siguiente error

[image: Error al intentar depurar desde VS Code]

Tengo la siguiente configuración:

En `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php`:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler= "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host= "localhost"
```

En `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
```

En este mismo archivo también he probado:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

El resultado sigue siendo el mismo. Me da el mismo error `Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded`.

También he probado instalando y desinstalando `php-xdebug`. Cuando no lo tengo instalado, directamente no xdebug ni intenta cargarse.

He probado a depurar el mismo problema con el IDE Netbeans y tampoco puedo depurar.

Al ejecutar `php -v` (o cualquier otro comando `php`) también recibo el mismo mensaje:

```
jonathan$ php -v
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2019 12:07:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

¿Me podéis echar una mano con este problema?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102014/discussion-on-question-by-jonathan-no-se-puede-depurar-php-en-visual-studio-code).